# Detecting if a web app is bookmarked to homescreen in Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

I've built a responsive web app which utilises some simple HTML and jQuery.  When the app is loaded in a mobile browser, a bootstrap `modal()` function is called which displays a simple 'bookmark to your homescreen' message.

For iOS I am able to check if the web app is being initialised from the homescreen bookmark via the following snippet:

```
  if(!window.navigator.standalone){
    $('#app-bookmarker').modal(); // popup the bookmark text
  }
```

If so, the `modal()` function doesn't get called, thus no popup..

I'm struggling to find a simple way to achieve the same process for Android, has anyone done something similar? Issue at the moment is that the popup will continue to display even when bookmarked..

Answer (score 5):

You can detect if the website has been added to the home screen in javascript like this:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
  console.log("Thank you for installing our app!");
}
```

More info on the official Google Developers documentation:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/display-mode

Comment: of `window.matchMedia('(display-mode: fullscreen)').matches` if you are using fullscreen mode

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can currently. If you look at the Chrome Developer page for the install to homescreen (https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen), there's an FAQ which states it's not possible.

`How can I detect if the app is running as an installed app?`

***`You can’t, directly.`***

EDIT: Actually, if you create a manifest.json for the app, you can specify a `start_url` parameter, see https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen#supporting

It feels a bit hacky, but could you append a querystring to that URL, e.g. `?fromhomescreen=yes` ? That way you can work out whether to display the popup or not based on that.